# rp_filter dropping packets in linux bridges+vlan_tagged interface + tap interfaces configuration

Tags: networking, centos, bridge

I've a linux bridge which has it's first interface as a `eth0.123` (VLAN tagged interface) & one or more `tap interfaces` created by kvm. (libvirt+kvm VM)

```
[root@compute1 ~]# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
brq732eb7f9-16          8000.002590c6438e       no              eth0.123
                                                        tap81474f06-29
                                                        tap81474f06-30
```

I noticed that, when I tried to ping IPs bound to VMs on tap interfaces, it used to work intermittently. Sometimes, the first VM spawned worked, sometimes the second worked. I fixed that problem by setting `rp_filter=0`.

`Question 1:` Gentleman at https://fvtool.wordpress.com/2013/04/19/install-kvm-on-centos-6-3-configure-networking-b/ has explained a similar problem but I fail to understand why it works the first time but doesn't work for other tap interfaces. Could anyone explain why rp_filter is dropping those ping packets? When `ping` worked on these machines, the `ssh` didn't work. It was weird.

`Question 2:` When I was debuging the problem, `tcpdump` on `eth0` revealed that I was recieveing both `ICMP request/reply` packets but still the sending machine reported 100% packet loss. Does `tcpdump` show packets even though they'll be eventually dropped by kernel?

Comment: answer to question 2: yes, tcpdump will show everything on the wire, even though e.g. `iptables` rules may drop those packets. Can't help with your question 1 unfortunately...